# Error CS1061 'DeviceClient' does not contain a definition for 'SetInputMessageHandlerAsync'

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iot, azure-iot-edge, .net-core-2.1, azure-iot-central

I try to build IoT Edge module termo sensor from the Microsoft sources. When I build project, I got the error:

> "Error    CS1061  'DeviceClient' does not contain a definition for
>   'SetInputMessageHandlerAsync' and no accessible extension method
>   'SetInputMessageHandlerAsync' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DeviceClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)"

[image: Source was built with error]

Then I created IoT Edge module from the scratch, compare assembly version and start building the module and everything was built ok.

[image: IoT module from the scratch was built Ok]

I follow to the DeviceClient class from the VS 2017 IDE for the app which is built ok.

[image: SetInputMessageHandlerAsync is available in DeviceClient class.]

But when I follow to the DeviceClient class in the application with building problem - I saw, that there is no such method.

[image: SetInputMessageHandlerAsync is absent in DeviceClient class.]

I compare assembly version - it's equal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the module from the scratch is used ModuleClient instead of DeviceClient in the Microsoft Sources. :-)